# Reordering items on mobile with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web

I have a website written in Bootstrap where among other things I have two .rows in a container with 3 items in each row, namely an image with some text below and whatnot. It looks good on desktops but i'm unsure how exactly to make the browser reorder things on mobile so that each item on the rows are listed one by one on top of each other with the items being centered and there being some spacing on either side of the items.

http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/2481/

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="nr2">

<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
<h1 id="tilbud">Header</h1>
<h3 id="tilbudsbes"> Description</h3>

</div>




<div class="row" style="margin-top:10%">

<div class="col-md-2"></div>
<div class="col-md-2">
<div>
<img src="Img/IMG.png" class="illustrasjon img-responsive">
<h4 class="tittel">Item</h4>
<div class="linje"></div>
<p class="prodBes">LOREM IPSUM HOIEFEOWIF BLA BLA BLA BLAH </p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-1"></div>
<div class="col-md-2">
<div>
<img src="Img/IMG.png" class="img-responsive">
<h4 class="tittel">Item</h4>
<div class="linje"></div>
<p class="prodBes">DESCRIPTION OIEHOIWEJF
  OIWJEFOIWEJFOIWEJFOI
  WJEOF EWKJFWEKFJN EFIWJEF WKEJF
  WEKJF WKJEF WKEJF WEF</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-1"></div>
<div class="col-md-2">
<div>

<img src="Img/IMG.png" class="img-responsive">
<h4 class="tittel">Item</h4>
<div class="linje"></div>
<p class="prodBes">EIOFJWEOIFJOIWE ITEM ITEM WEIFOJWEOFJOIWEFOIEJWF</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2"></div>
</div>
</div>


<div class="row" style="">

<div class="col-sm-2"></div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
<div>
<img src="Img/IMG.png" class="illustrasjon img-responsive">
<h4 class="tittel">Item</h4>
<div class="linje"></div>
<p class="prodBes">LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET </p>
</div>

</div>
<div class="col-sm-1"></div>

<div class="col-sm-2">
<div>
<img src="Img/IMG.png" class="img-responsive">
<h4 class="tittel">Item</h4>
<div class="linje"></div>
<p class="prodBes">LOREM LOREM IPSUM UPS</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-1"></div>

<div class="col-sm-2">
<div>

<img src="Img/IMG.png" class="img-responsive">
<h4 class="tittel">Item</h4>
<div class="linje"></div>
<p class="prodBes">BLAH BØAH OIEHWFOIWHEFOIHWE
  IOFHOWIEFOIWEFOIWEF</p>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The reason i have empty columns on either side of the rows is so that there will be spacing between items as well as the page. I know I could use padding or margins for spacing but then the items aren't centered on the page.

Any help would be very much appreciated. :)

Comment: I can see like following as mentioned only " each item on the rows are listed one by one on top of each other with the items being centered". How do you expect the output to be ?

Comment: You want Bootstrap's `push` and `pull` grid classes.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this in all the div's you have been used so far:

`text-center` is used for centering the text ,
`center block` is used for centering the image

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 text-center ">
  <div>
    <img src="Img/IMG.png" class="illustrasjon img-responsive center-block">
    <h4 class="tittel">Item</h4>
    <div class="linje"></div>
    <p class="prodBes">LOREM IPSUM HOIEFEOWIF BLA BLA BLA BLAH </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

## [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/CZLeQ5cbDL)

Answer (score -1):

Hello look at the bootstrap docs they really good. It explains there how to use the classes.

You have lg md sm xs and you can apply more than 1 of these classes at a time. They target different screen sizes. Md is the norm used as it behaves well on most devices. But if you want superior control you need to apply more than one class.

Comment: Please be more specific while answering the question.

Comment: I see what your saying arshad but in this case the documents are excellent regarding this and I would just be copying the docs. Here is a link to the docs. http://getbootstrap.com/css/